# Create POST route doesn't have a prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes.rb has the following:

```
namespace :admin do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  resources :users
end
```

I don't see a prefix for the admin/users#create path for some reason?

rake routes shows:

```
 POST   /admin/users(.:format)          admin/users#create
```

I thought it would be:

```
admin_incidents_create POST   /admin/incidents(.:format)          admin/incidents#create
```

Because of this, I can't create my form tag correctly:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: ??? do |f| %>
```

Why isn't the create_path prefix appearing in my rake routes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `namespace` in form_for, like this

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

please see this for more detail: [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)